# Are most Cabal packages actually being maintained?

Tags: haskell

I wanted to try and see if Haskell can actually be used for game development (I heard about FRP, but I'm not sure if it can solve the issues I imagine there are elegantly - I am reading http://theses.fh-hagenberg.at/thesis/Meisinger10 right now to learn about it)

Anyways - so here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952841/exemplary-haskell-game-code I read that LambdaHack would be a good example - it seems to work, but there also seems to be a lot of deprecated code in it and it's dependencies (I got a LOT of "Don't use this, this will be removed in the next version"-kind of warnings. Are those packages actually being maintained anymore, or should I look for something else that is?

Comment: The answer is probably "no, most packages are not being maintained" although this buys you very little and you'll still need to do research on each individually.

Comment: https://github.com/kosmikus shows the usual graph for the last 52 weeks' commit history for LambdaHack. By the way, line 142 from the .cabal file reads `ghc-options:     -Wall -fwarn-orphans -fwarn-tabs -fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns -fwarn-incomplete-record-updates -fwarn-monomorphism-restriction -fwarn-unrecognised-pragmas` You can strike this if signs of the ghc's never-ending change are too alarming :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several thousand open source libraries on Hackage (somewhere above 4000 at this point). As for any open source library collection, they have varying levels of maintainer commitment. It is up to you to use the data published about the package to determine if it meets your level of quality.

In fact, the rate of new library production is growing literally exponentially:

[image]

Measuring maintainer commitment is one of the possible metrics to consider when choosing a library to use. To aid in this, we show the maintainer's release record.

Comment: I dispute that that graph shows something that is growing "literally exponentially" (time from 500-1000 is 1.5 units, 1000-2000 is 2.5 units and 2000-4000 is 4 units - these should all be the same if the growth was exponential) but otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: Here is it on a log Y scale: http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/thumb/b/b3/Hackage-cumulative.svg/600px-Hackage-cumulative.svg.png showing the slowing rate of acceleration.